# _NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've viewed all of the other questions on this topic and they seem to have issues that do not pertain to my code.   I've struggled with this for a while and am hoping that another set of eyes will see where I have gone wrong.   I have put breakpoints in various areas of the code.  There is a breakpoint with `NSLog(@"number of rows, %lu",(unsigned long)self.eventContent.count);` in the "TableView numberOfRowsInSection" Section that returns: "number of rows,3".   I also have a breakpoint in the "tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath" Section with `NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath. %lu",(long)indexPath.row);` which returns:

```
"cellForRowAtIndexPath. 0"
"cellForRowAtIndexPath. 1"
```

The error occurs at 1 on the line beginning with cell.titleLabel.text.   When I take out the comments on the NSLogs following, I can see that the first cell generates o.k.

Can someone please direct me to where else I might look?
So thanking you in advance...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"number of rows, %lu",(unsigned long)self.eventContent.count);
    return self.eventContent.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    EQCalendarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Get the event at the row selected and display its title
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath. %lu",(long)indexPath.row);
    cell.titleLabel.text = [[[eventContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"title"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  //Fails here

    cell.notesLabel.text = [[[eventContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"notes"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.startTimeLabel.text = [[[eventContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"startTime"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.endTimeLabel.text = [[[eventContent   objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"endTime"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
```

Comment: You're asking for an element that isn't there.  It couldn't be any plainer!  Since you don't provide us with the identity of the failing line (which you would get from the exception stack trace), we can't say for sure that the array lacking said entry is `eventContent`, but it sure looks like it.

Comment: You're logging `indexPath.row`, but your code is using `indexPath.section` to access the `eventContent` array, then accessing various elements of a dictionary with `objectForKey:`, and then using `indexPath.row` to access the results. We have no way of knowing what's in those dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

In number of rows in section you're using the `self.eventsList` array, whereas in your cellForRow method you're asking for the `objectAtIndex:` of the `eventContent` array. Chances are you messed up the two, because `eventContent` clearly does not have as many rows as the `eventsList`

Comment: You're quick! That was a bit silly.   I have changed the code and have  "NSLog(@"number of rows, %lu",(unsigned long)eventContent.count);" which returns "number of rows, 3" in the "numberOfRowsInSection" Section.   I still get the same error though.   The exception occurs at the line: "cell.titleLabel.text = [[[eventContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"title"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" just below the NSLog for "cellForRowAtIndexPath" in the "tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath" Section

Comment: I also replaced the self.eventsList.count to eventContent.count.

Comment: @user3331154 - The message means what is says.  Read it very carefully.

Comment: I know what the message says and what it means.   I just can't see where the bound is set at 0.   While I appreciate your input, your comment is not helpful.

Comment: @user3331154 - The bound is set to zero when there aren't any entries in the array.